# How can I pass array from wpf control to javascript function in webbrowser control?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I can send one argument, but can't send an array.

C# code:

```
string[] mes = {"Bascketball Stadium", "New Address", "Ilya"};
this.MyWebBrowser.InvokeScript("DaveWriter", mes);
```

JavaScript code:

```
function DaveWriter(mes){
   var arr = jQuery.makeArray(mes);         
   document.getElementById('company').innerHTML = arr[0];
   document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = arr[1];           
}
```

I recieve only the 1st element of the array.

What should I change to recieve all elements?

Answer (score 1):

Very tricky because the InvokeScript takes the arguments as an array. So for example, you're really passing 3 parameters there, not an array of parameters, each of the elements of `mes` would be one argument to `DaveWriter`. Meaning, if you changed it to:

```
function DaveWriter(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
// Your code
}
```

It would be there. There isn't, from what I've seen, a clean method to do what you want. Some recommend JSON, then evaluating the JSON in JavaScript. I don't like that idea because you have to use `eval()` which makes me feel wrong.

Here's what I suggest. What if you pass it like you are, then access it via the `arguments` variable. See [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2Farguments) for more information. 
Basically:

```
function DaveWriter(mes){ 
   document.getElementById('company').innerHTML = arguments[0];
   document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = arguments[1];           
}
```

It's not ideal, but it will allow you to do what you want. I don't believe there are many other options. Maybe someone knows of a cleaner way, but this should work for you. I didn't have an opportunity to test that fully as I don't have a WPF application with a WebBrowser handy, but I think that will accomplish what you need.

Comment: If you feel this is the correct answer to your question, please mark this as the answer, that way it will help others in the community with the same question find it.